# Swing: Can't set colour of jtextfield inside a panel with image

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel which has a background image. To this panel, I add a JTextField, and set the background color to that that text field.
I expected the background to get the colour, but it is being overriden by the background image of panel.

Is this expected behavior? If not, how to get around it?

Comment: Does it happen if you use regular button (without image)?

Comment: Buttons seem to be rendering as expected... but not the text field. I just noticed that even if I remove the background image from the outer JPanel, the text field does not get the colour. If it helps, the overall structure is JDialog, JPanel, JPanel, JTextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your textfield is opaque.

Swing behaviour depends on many properties and layouts. You can try to debug your swing components with [this tool](http://www.swingexplorer.com/) and make some experiments with properties(background, opaque, ...).